# Why don't I get the full html code when GET requesting with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

For some reason, when I use the python library 'requests', to GET request a [website](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dragon-Ball-Z-Mug-SON-Goku-Mug-Hot-Changing-Color-Cups-Heat-Reactive-Mugs-and-Cups/32649664569.html)'s html code. It doesn't return the full html code.

What is happening?

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dragon-Ball-Z-Mug-SON-Goku-Mug-Hot-Changing-Color-Cups-Heat-Reactive-Mugs-and-Cups/32649664569.html'

mess = requests.get(url)

print(mess.text, '\n', '_'*20)

approved = []
images = re.findall(r'(?<=src=")[a-zA-Z0-9 \/\\,._-]+(?=")', mess.text)

for image in images:
    print(image)
    base, ext = image.rsplit('.', 1)

    if ext == 'png' or ext == 'jpg' or ext == 'JPG':
        approved.append(image)
```

Output:

---

```
//u.alicdn.com/js/aplus_ae.js
//i.alicdn.com/ae-header/20170208145626/buyer/front/ae-header.js
```

This picture shows that there is an 'img' tag with the attribute 'src' which is a jpg. But for some reason, it's not captured in the output.

Comment: [Don't use regex to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2482744). Use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Many (most?) modern websites include dynamic content that is generated on-the-fly via Javascript.  This content will not be available in the response to a `GET` request. It's possible you are encountering this situation.

Comment: What should I do @larsks to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch elements from html content, there are very sophisticated modules available such as lxml, BeautifulSoup, etc.

You can use **lxml** to achieve this which is order of magnitude faster than **BeautifulSoup** something like this :

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Dragon-Ball-Z-Mug-SON-Goku-Mug-Hot-Changing-Color-Cups-Heat-Reactive-Mugs-and-Cups/32649664569.html'

mess = requests.get(url).content

root = html.fromstring(mess)
print(root.xpath('//a[@class="ui-image-viewer-thumb-frame"]/img/@src'))
```

This will result in :

```
['https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB16NR_MpXXXXa5XpXXq6xXFXXX0/Dragon-Ball-Z-Mug-SON-Goku-Mug-Hot-Changing-Color-Cups-Heat-Reactive-Mugs-and-Cups.jpg_640x640.jpg']
```

Ypu can refer to the [documentation here](http://lxml.de/parsing.html) for more exploration.

Comment: 1. What does: "html.fromstring()" ?
2. instead of using xpath to search for the specific img, is it possible to search for all img tags instead?

Comment: Yes,` root.xpath('//img/@src')`. I would recommend you to read the documentation.